# Concrete5 isEditMode()-like handler to get Information about active editing or publishing

Tags: content-management-system, publishing, editing, concrete5

So my question is if there is a Concrete 5 handler/listener instead of

```
isEditMode()
```

that tells if the user is in active Editing mode or if he just has published his Edit?

Something like

isPublished() or isEditModeActive()

Thx yall

---

thanks for your interest!

So i tried the Eventhandler in the way it is decumented in the second example:
 1. i created site_events.php in the /config 
 2. i added

```
<?PHP Events::extendPageType('inhalt', 'on_page_version_approve');?>
```

1. i added to the site.php

   define('ENABLE_APPLICATION_EVENTS', true);
2. on the reffered inhalt.php pagetype i added

   function on_page_version_approve() {
   echo "page published";
   }

... nothing happens.
In the description it is written, that the refferring inhalt.php has to exist in /controllers. However, this is not the case. I actually dont quite understand the structure of the Eventhandling. It would be great if you could help me out there...
Thanks in advance anyways :)

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking? isEditMode() tells you if the user is in active editing mode. If the user is not in editing mode than the page is published. (Or are you asking how to tell if the page has been published vs. if it is in preview mode?)

Comment: What i was looking for is a possibillity to hook into the action pf publishing. SO to say if someone edited something and presses "publish" there would appear something like "your stuff has been published".

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the documentation (which is understandable -- it is written very poorly, and it looks like English is not your native language). What you need to do is put an `inhalt` function in your page type's controller. For example, if your page type handle is `blog_post`, then the controller for that would be in `/controllers/page_types/blog_post.php`, and the contents of that file would be `class BlogPostPageTypeController extends Controller { public function inhalt() { ... } }`

Comment: Although it might not be working because the event might be fired when the save action is first done, not when the page is viewed again (that is, the system sends a redirect back to the page after it has fired the event). In this case, you need to set something in the session (via `$_SESSION['is_page_published'] = true;`), then read the session in the page type template -- e.g. `if (!empty($_SESSION['is_page_published'])) { echo 'page published'; }

Comment: thanks for the advices. So far i am not that much into the details of C5 and its structure. My pagetype handle has the same name as my pagetype (inhalt)... can this cause problems?

Comment: I don't think that would be the problem, but it won't hurt to change it. Maybe call the event handler something more descriptive like `inhalt_on_page_version_approve`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want what concrete5 calls Events (http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/system/events/).

As per the docs, you'll get the `Page` as arguments to the functions you register.

There is nothing quite as specific as what you're looking for, but:

1. For published, use `on_page_version_approve`.
2. For editing, try `on_before_render`. It's a bit generic (ie, it'll be getting called far more than you're interested), but you can do something like `if ($page->getCollectionCheckedOutUserID())`. You should experiment a bit with this, though. For example, if you check out the home page for editing, and then someone else loads the live version, the event will probably get called again, and the `Page` will probably show "checked out". But maybe you can check `->isEditMode()`, which should check it against the logged in user...